# Android SDK Synchronize Error

Tags: android, sdk

I keep getting the a error after trying to add a library to my project, however all i did was cause a error.

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project ':library'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

I have read up on the problem but what they suggest i have already done such as changing the version shown below to one above, but they have always been as shown below.

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
```

I thought it could have been the minimum version so i change it but still no change.

```
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

Both of them are above the required version yet i keep getting the error, any ideas on what is causing the error?. 
The problem still occurs after i have removed the library i was trying to import now i am just left with an error that wasn't there before.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Gradle File

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "quiz.quiz"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your SDK Manager and update your SDK Build Tools. See if that works. This is how mine looks.

[image]

Comment: I check and there all up to date.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and rebuild? Can you also post your gradle file to see exactly what is going on.